# PHP: Get PDF-file into variable and embed PDF in modal

Tags: php, html, pdf, file-get-contents

is it possible to use `file_get_contents` to store the content of an pdf and embed this content later into a modal (HTML-page) to show the file to the user?

I would like to create a preview of PDF and image files without giving the user the possibility to download these files directly. Because of this the directory of the files has restricted access using `.htaccess`.

Comment: Not something you can do just with PHP.  Take a look at ghostscript for PDF management.

Comment: first paragraph - that can all be done with php, 2nd im not sure about preview image

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ImageMagick extenstion for this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');

$filePath = '/path/to/pdf/file.pdf';
$image = new Imagick("{$filePath}[0]"); // [0] means "first page"
$image->setImageFormat('jpg');

// if you want, you can also crop and/or resize the image
// see the docs at php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php for more

echo $image;
exit;
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you, I'll have a look at it and report if it works or not :-)

Comment: Hm, unfortunately this does not work for me at the moment.

This is what I coded: http://d.pr/1ghCT and this is what I get: http://d.pr/1i2IA

Comment: Looks like a different header (and some payload) had already been sent to the client. Can you check the actual header that the browser received?